# 301 Redirect, mod_rewrite disabled

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

if mod_rewrite disabled, is there *any* other way to redirect a domain to another one?

Using htaccess too or any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect the whole domain to another one use:

```
Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com/
```

Edit: To redirect a specific subdirectory use:

```
Redirect 301 /dir http://new.com/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I want to redirect specific directory and subdirectories to a URL (not the same directory in the new URL, like, `http://old.com/dir` to `http://new.com/`)

Comment: redirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ `http://new.com`
redirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ `http://new.com`
like this?